# Анимация слайдера

Tags: анимация, slider, javascript, css

На сайте http://vk.cc/3cejAt слайдер при перелистывании продвигается немного дальше, потом становится на место. Как убрать этот эффект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо у `.csslider > ul > li` убрать или заменить параметр трансформации `cubic-bezier`.
Заменить можно на `ease`.

Вот [тут](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2011/07/transformaciya-css.html) почитайте для общего развития.